# npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

While installing Angular cli using the command:
npm install -g @angular/cli
I am getting this warning.
I am using node version 16.17.0 and npm version 8.19.2

I wanted to install angular cli. But ng command not working

Comment: Could you please show the error?

Comment: Have you manage to get ride of this warning.?

Answer (score 11):

To solve this problem perform following steps:

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm cache verify

npm install -g @angular/cli

ng version
After this moment if you see that powershell is not allowing to execute the script
follow following steps  from this site:

[Chaman Gautam](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-ps1-can-not-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-sys/)

and then run ng version(or any ng command you will be able to)
if you see angular

[image]

you are good to go !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the command `'ng v'` and check if it asks any question about sharing data about this project with the Angular Team at Google google or any question at all about google say `N` as no. If it shows angular versions then it means angular/cli is installed

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning, the package might have installed on your system.
In my case package was installed but it did not recognize the ng command.

- so make sure first if the package is installed or not, to check run the below command-

`npm list -g`

Here you will see a list of all packages you installed...

- If angular is there take the path for the angular package, you can do this by firing the below command-

`npm list -g @angular/cli`

Now next step is to Add the installation directory to your system's PATH environment variable.

The steps for doing this vary depending on your operating system.

Windows for example-:

1. Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables".
2. Click on "Edit the system environment variables", then click the "Environment
   Variables" button.
3. Under "System Variables", find the "Path" variable and click "Edit".
4. Click on **New** , add path you got above and click on **OK**.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem recently. I tried uninstalling angular and reinstalling it but there were already 'ng' files at the location:

```
C:/Users/<your_user_name>/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

To resolve the issue, go to that npm folder and delete the following files:

- ng
- ng.cmd
- ng.ps1

Once these files are removed, reinstall angular cli. Follow the guide here to clear the cache and do a clean install:
[https://www.javatpoint.com/uninstall-and-reinstall-angular-cli][1]

The ng command should work now. Check with the below command

```
ng --version
```

References:
[1]: https://www.javatpoint.com/uninstall-and-reinstall-angular-cli