# error when i try to use the yeoman code generator,it fails, but i did like on the youtube video

Tags: node.js, git, powershell, visual-studio-code

so i wanted to create a extension pack for vscode, first i installed node.js then git, then i did

```
npm install -global yo
```

i got these warns

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

changed 734 packages in 59s

82 packages are looking for funding
```

but i thought it is okay and kept going this time installing the code generator

```
npm install -global yo generator-code
```

and got these three warns:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

changed 921 packages in 7m

84 packages are looking for funding
```

and then after typing

```
yo code
```

it throws an error (rus, orig):

```
yo : Невозможно загрузить файл C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой
системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execution_Policies по адресу https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?L
inkID=135170.
строка:1 знак:1
+ yo code
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

the same error, but google-translated:

```
yo : Unable to upload file C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo.ps1 , since script execution is disabled on this
system. For more information, see about_performing_police at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?L
inkID=135170.
string:1 sign:1
+ + code yo
+ ~~
+ + Category Information : Security Error: (:) [], Securityexception Exception
+ + Fully Qualified Error ID : Unauthorized Access
```

can someone help me please?

i tried reinstalling nodejs, that didnt help at all, also tried searching for other ways to create an extension pack, found nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+script+execution+is+disabled+on+this+system

Answer (score 0):

Execution of arbitrary scripts is disabled in your Windows installation, if you go to the [link provided in error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3) you can see how to enable it, tldr (run in powershell as **administrator!**):

```bash
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
# You will see a list with all Execution policy probably set to Undefined

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine

Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
# You should see that the policy for LocalMachine is set to Unrestricted
# For changes to take an effect you have to restart each shell that should use this new policy
# (so you need to close all opened vscode instances, or easier you can just restart windows)
```

Comment: i used all the commands, i made sure that it is set to unrestricted, but i still get the following warnings while installing "yo" by npm
```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
```

Comment: Well they are just warnings so it should work anyway, you can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337166/npm-warn-deprecated-npmcli-move-file2-0-1-this-functionality-has-been-moved-t)